# Sitecore: Get value of droplink in repeater

Tags: sitecore

I have the following;

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater">
<ItemTemplate>
        <sc:image field="image from droplink" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

"Image from droplink" is a droplink selected value (a Sitecore content item). Within this item, there is a field "Image" which is the actual media item i want the source of. So the above does not work, as this field just returns the GUID of the content item.

How do I get the image src from the Image field of the droplink selected item in the above repeater?

Comment: What does your droplink point to? Media assets?

Comment: Sorry - it points to a content item, which then in turn has a field "image" pointing to a media item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to populate the `Item` or `Datasource` property on the sc:Image tag with the actual item containing the Image field. `Item` would be an `Item` object, whereas `Datasource` can be an ID or path. I think the following should do it.

```
<sc:Image runat="server" Field="image field" Datasource="<%# ((Item)Container.DataItem)["droplink field"] %>" />
```

Comment: I get an "The type or namespace name 'Container' could not be found.." with the line '<sc:image field="image" Datasource='<%# ((Container.DataItem)Item)["droplink field"] %>' runat="server" />'. '<sc:link runat="server" Item='<%# Container.DataItem %>' Field="link" />' works fine however?

Comment: "Datasource='<%# ((Item)Container.DataItem)["droplink field"] %>'" - worked :)

Comment: Woops! Coding on the fly. Edited answer and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**The following answer assumes that the droplink on the Context Item points to a Media Item. (Prior to questioner clarification). Might be useful for someone else.**

You'll need to use an asp:Image and a [OnItemDataBound](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/repeater-onitemdatabound-cs.aspx) handler in your code behind, and use `e.Item.DataItem` (where e is `RepeaterItemEventArgs`) to get the item being bound. Ensure `e.ItemType` is a `ListItemType.Item`. From there it will be something like...

```
var item = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;
var dropLink = new InternalLinkField(item.Fields["image from droplink"]);
var mediaItem = dropLink.TargetItem;
if (mediaItem != null)
{
  var options = new MediaOptions { Height = 100, Width = 100 }; //change to your dimensions
  var imageUrl = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(new MediaItem(mediaItem), options);
  var imageControl = e.Item.FindControl("myImageControlID"); //change to asp:Image ID
  imageControl.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
  imageControl.AlternateText = mediaItem.Alt;
}
```

If you are supporting Page Editor (I hope you are!), within a repeater you can use [Edit Frames](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/) to allow editing of the image on each item. (Note that the linked example puts an edit frame around a whole `ListView`, whereas you'll want to place it within your `Repeater` and databind the `Datasource` property to the current item ID.)

Comment: It's actually a sitecore content item droplink points to. Within this, there is a field "Image" which is the actual media item i want the source of.

Comment: Added a new answer based on this clarification.